# how do you color percentage of a textview in android?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I know Spannable can help me color any specific letters in a textview. However, is it possible to color 1/2 or 1/3 of a letter. I wanted to color text within a textview by percentage instead of by letter. Thanks for reading, and please let me know if you had some idea or solution to this.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It may be easier to use Spanned thought [android.text.HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)</strike>

So something like this:

```
Spanned text = HTML.fromHtml("Sp<span style=\"color:red\">ann</span>able");
textView.setText(text);
```

It can also be used to add images, but it a bit more complicated.

---

**UPDATE**

I re-read your question and thought of a solution. You could create a custom view that has two `textView`s in a `FrameLayout` (on top of each other) and then resize the one on the top relative to the percentage. Something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProgressTextView extends FrameLayout {

    private TextView backgroundTextView;
    private TextView foregroundTextView;
    private CharSequence text;

    private ProgressTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private ProgressTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private ProgressTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        backgroundTextView = new TextView(context);
        foregroundTextView = new TextView(context);
        addView(backgroundTextView);
        addView(foregroundTextView);
        // process custom attributeSet from xml to set the colours
    }

    public void setBackgroundTextColor(int color) {
        backgroundTextView.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setBackgroundTextColor(ColorStateList colors) {
        backgroundTextView.setTextColor(colors);
    }

    public void setForegroundTextColor(int color) {
        backgroundTextView.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void setForegroundTextColor(ColorStateList colors) {
        backgroundTextView.setTextColor(colors);
    }

    public void setPercentage(float per) {
        foregroundTextView.setWidth((((float) backgroundTextView.getWidth()) / 100f) * per);
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        this.text = text;
        backgroundTextView.setText(text);
        foregroundTextView.setText(text);
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

PS: not tested ;) just an idea

---

**MORE UPDATE**

Apparently, with this method the text gets shortened instead of just cropped as I expected. The maybe on creation of the foregroundTextView you could do this:

```
foregroundTextView = new TextView(context) {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect bounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        bounds.right (((float) bounds.right) / 100.0f) * per;
        canvas.clipRect(bounds);
    }
};
```

And also add the `per` variable and modify `setPercentage(float per)` to be just a setter:

```
private float per = 0.0f;

public void setPercentage(float per) {
    this.per = per;
}
```

Hope this one works ;)

Comment: Edit: Forgot the resizing of the the foreground textview

Comment: After some modification, I tested and ran the code above. It runs but still it only highlights by letter. But thanks for your precious time and idea, really appreciated. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You could draw the letters yourself on a canvas. Each letter consisting of a bunch of interconnected arcs, that way you could style each individually.

Having to draw each letter would be considerably painstaking though, e.g., paint.setColor(), canvas.drawArc(), paint.setColor(), canvas.drawArc(), and so on...

Comment: Would be easier to use `drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint)`

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking though. If I'm not mistaken, he wants to style each letter of the text individually, coloring only **portions** of each letter. For example- take the letter "A", and color the top third red, the middle third green, and the bottom third blue. A very intriguing idea, would be interested to see the result.

Comment: He doesn't say if it's vertical or horizontal percentage. Although either doing the drawText limiting the area of painting or with the composite method I said apply to this case as well (with a bit more work of course)

Comment: i am trying to color percentage a letter(or words) horizontally, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so if i have a textview with text "hello world". i wanted to be able to color from left to right by percentage instead of by letter. again thanks all for reading and helping out. greatly appreciated. ^_^

Comment: ah, ic. pablicso has a good idea below, but again it will only color whole letters. coloring partial letters will require some kind of wizardry on your part, similar to my idea above. maybe a combination of the two? it definitely won't be something automated.

Answer (score -1):

create a drawable and override it's onDraw method and paint canvas how you wish and set it as background to your textview